# Why can't you omit the array size in a new initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This is allowed:

```
int a[]{1, 2, 3};
```

But not this:

```
auto a = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

You have to specify the bounds. Why?

EDIT: The proper syntax (that doesn't compile) is:

```
auto a = new (int[]){1, 2, 3};
```

This gives the real error message, which is:

```
error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
```

Comment: Sounds like an oversight. I doubt that it's intentional.

Comment: because `operator new[]` requires a size parameter. Why not use a vector instead?

Comment: @RedAlert I think the question is why the compiler can't infer the size parameter. Ultimately the answer is "because the grammar doesn't allow it," but I think the intent of this question is "why isn't that part of the grammar," to which we can only speculate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was intentionally left out of the grammar changes in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm

Comment: @cdhowie compilers don't do it for `std::array` either. This property is unique to stack allocated raw arrays, probably because that's how it works in C.

Comment: @RedAlert Right, we can excuse the compiler for omitting this feature for a type that (while part of the standard library) isn't part of the language grammar itself -- but raw arrays are a language-level construct.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1469

Comment: I can't find the part of the spec that forbids this. `new int[]{...}` is forbidden because the expression between the square brackets is not optional in *noptr-new-declarator* but with `new (int[]){...}`, the `int[]` part gets parsed using the *type-id* production instead of the *new-type-id* production. So this syntax is grammatically correct, but apparently is ill-formed for a reason I'm unable to locate in the standard.

Comment: @cdhowie, in `new (int[]){...}` you have an incomplete type. [dcl.array] says "An array bound may also be omitted when the declarator is followed by an initializer (8.5). In this case the bound is calculated from the number of initial elements (say, N) ..." but you don't have a declarator, you have a new-expression

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah, right. And in the C++11 standard [expr.new] §5.3.4 we have *"This type shall be a complete object type ..."* Of course. It's so simple.

Comment: @cdhowie, yep, that's my interpretation anyway ... I wouldn't swear by it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MSalters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557262/501250) addresses why this hasn't been changed in recent versions of the standard.  Here I will answer the companion question, "where in the C++11 standard is this forbidden?"

### Regarding `new (int[]){1, 2, 3}`

First, we need to note that `int[]` is an incomplete type.

> ... an array of unknown size ... is an incompletely-defined object type.  -[basic.types] §3.9 ¶5

Finally, we note that the `new` operator does not permit the specified type to be incomplete:

> This type shall be a complete object type ... -[expr.new] §5.3.4 ¶1

There isn't anything in the standard to make an exception for this case when the *braced-init-list* syntax is used.

### Regarding `new int[]{1, 2, 3}`

`int[]` in this case gets parsed using the *new-type-id* production, which uses the *noptr-new-declarator* production to parse the square brackets:

> *noptr-new-declarator:*
>     [ *expression* ] *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>     *noptr-new-declarator* [ *constant-expression* ] *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*

Note that *expression* is not marked optional, therefore this syntax simply fails to parse.

Answer (score 5):

As Jonathan Wakely already pointed out in the comments, this is in fact a closed issue. The resolution "should be handled in Evolution Work Group" essentially means WG21 thinks it's not a bad idea per se, but at the same time they don't consider it a defect in the current standard. Which makes sense - there's no hint somewhere that is should work, it's just by analogy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the compiler read files in serial method, it never goes back, (that's why you must use forward declarations for example, and not just wait for function to be declared later). I'm not sure it is the official reason but it just make sense to me.

This is my explanation:

The line `int Array[]={1,2,3};` can be processed in serial way like this:

start array: put 1 in the 1st place, put 2 in the 2nd, put three in the 3rd, end array, therefore: array size is 3 integers, so move the stack frame by this size.

But the following line: `int *p=new int[]{1,2,3};` should have start with memory allocation, in addition to placing elements in the memory and detect the size. How can it done in a serial way?

To allow something like this you must break the seriality principle, and begin the processing from the end and then go back to call the appropriate allocation size.

**EDIT:**

In response to the 1st comment

I did some test, in the following code:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        err2 error;
        cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
    }
    err1 error;
};
```

the compiler appear to leave the inline functions to be compiled as though they come after the class.

The evidence is that no matter the order, member errors detected before function errors. 
So in the sample class, I'm getting `err1 error` before `err2 error`, even though the chronological order is the opposite.

Therefore I guess classes are the exceptional, otherwise in-class functions was very limited in usage of the class itself.

**EDIT2:**

`int Array[]={sizeof(Array)};` gives error, the only reason is the size of array is given after the closing of the array. it is more similar to the problem in the question than `int Array[]={1,2};`

Comment: This principle is already broken in C++: `class A { public: A() : foo(0) { } private: int foo; };`. (`A::foo` is used in the constructor initializer list before it is declared.)

Comment: You are right here, I guess classes are the exceptional, i made some tests, you can see my edit and tell me what you think.

Comment: Even still, your explanation makes little sense. The compiler would have to "go backward" to adjust the type of `Array` to be `int[3]`. The reason you can leave off the array dimension in this case has nothing to do with the "serial" nature of the language, rather it's because it's *explicitly allowed* by the standard.

Comment: I guess your answer, about the `new` must get a complete type, it is the correct answer. still when you consider the c and c++ languages, the serialization of code is one of the principle of the language, even if it had not officially declared so. it is not an iron rule, just a guide line, which can be broken sometimes when needed (like in classes and `auto` variables)